# How to setup python-linter for Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor, linter

How do I setup a linter for python? I am using Atom, I have the base linter, but it does not show any error lines (those red lines underneath errors). ANY help would be appreciated.

[The settings for the extiension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo8wz.png)

[and the other one cause i couldnt fit it in one image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcjn4.png)

[see, it wont show an error even when i use linter:lint](https://youtu.be/hro3CUXF9Xc)

[image: look, there is an error, click here]

Comment: Have you actually installed [`linter-python`](https://github.com/pchomik/linter-python)? Did you install its requirement `pylama`? Did you [configure](https://github.com/pchomik/linter-python#plugin-configuration) it? Please [edit] your question to add all the details.

Comment: `Python39\Scripts` I believe is a directory. Where is `pylama` installed?

Comment: yes, pylama.exe is installed over there

Comment: Have you tried closing and reopening Atom? Do you have any other extensions that might be disabling the linter? (IIRC, `python-ide` does that.) Is `python-linter` enabled? Are you able to run `pylama` and `pylint` outside of Atom?

Comment: how do i enable python linter?

also i have tried running pylama and pylint outside of atom and i reopened atom but it still wont work

Comment: Click **View issue** and see what it says

Comment: YOOOOO, IT WORKS, PYTHON-LINTERS IS ANOTHER PACKAGE AND THAT WORKS.

Comment: The error on the screenshot makes me wonder how you installed the package. It looks like it's missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

[`linter-python`](https://github.com/pchomik/linter-python) has been inactive since 2017. Use [`linter-pylama`](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-pylama) instead, though it's also been inactive since 2019.

Answer (score -1):

[`python-linters`](https://atom.io/packages/python-linters) works where `linter-python` and `linter-pylama` didn't.